# PHP, Mongodb, BulkWrite

Tags: php, mongodb

I need to insert records into the mongodb database. I read the documentation and made a query using BulkWrite. But it inserts only 1 record and ends with an error:

Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: BulkWrite objects may only be executed once and this instance has already been executed

PHP script:

```
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://user:pass@ip:27017');

$lines = file('name.txt');

$document = array();

foreach ($lines as $row) {

        $document[] = array( 
            "name" => $row, 
            "description" => "all", 
        );

        $insert = $bulk->insert($document);

        $result = $manager->executeBulkWrite('test.collection', $bulk);
}
```

Why is it executed only once and not until the file runs out?

How do I make the loop work correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to have the `bulk.execute` _outside and after_ the for-loop.

Comment: @prasad_, When i try add entries (50k) i get error:
precondition failed: (buffer->datalen + data_size) < INT_MAX

Do you know how this resolve? 

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to include the PHP, MongoDB and PHP Driver versions in your post. Also, check if you have the latest driver installed (this is not a solution) - it generally helps.

Comment: @prasad_, PHP v 7.0.33, Mongo 5.0.6